# trying it integrate prismic prismicio with angular js

Tags: angularjs, prismic.io

Hey people i am trying to integrate prismic io with angular js 1 but it is not working.

I referred to many links to do that but i don't get anything data.

https://github.com/awulder/angular-prismicio

https://gist.github.com/laradevitt/94f7e21eaf6d3441b9475fc8f5201201

http://jsfiddle.net/othermachines/bbv9dzug/

and that's my code :

[my code](http://plnkr.co/edit/mHYZhgNxI67O7U4rlRT0?p=preview)

**app.js**

```
// Define the `myApp` module
var app = angular.module('app', ['prismic.io']);

app.config(function(PrismicProvider) {
    PrismicProvider.setApiEndpoint('https://myname.prismic.io/api');
    PrismicProvider.setAccessToken('i put my access token');
    PrismicProvider.setClientId('i used my id');
    PrismicProvider.setClientSecret('i put my secret');
    PrismicProvider.setLinkResolver(function(ctx, doc) {
        return 'detail.html?id=' + doc.id + '&slug=' + doc.slug + ctx.maybeRefParam;
    });
});
// Define the `AppCtrl` controller on the `app` module
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['Prismic', function(Prismic) {
    var self = this;
    Prismic.all().then(function(data) {
        self.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/prismic.io/dist/prismic.io.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awulder/angular-prismicio/master/dist/angular-prismicio.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<prismic-html fragment="data.fragment"></prismic-html>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">
      <span>{{item.slug}}</span>

    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The idea with this Prismic thing is that it has the data on it and they are just providing some code for integration and then we read this json data using angular.
please if anyone used it before will be really nice to help.
thanks

Comment: Could you add your relevant code into this question?

Comment: inlined code from jsfiddle

Comment: @Alexei hey i got it but i still facing some problem with making my links SEO friendly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840022/getting-links-using-slug-instead-of-id-to-be-seo-friendly-urls-integrating-prism